# Convert negative currency values stored as text

Tags: excel

I regularly copy and paste values into an Excel spreadsheet and use the VALUE() function to convert them from text to numbers. However the following value is not getting converted and results in a #VALUE error:

```
−£13.24
```

I could do some complex string manipulation to remove the currency symbol, but just wondered if there was a simpler solution.

Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT: I have just realised that it is not the currency symbol that is causing the problem, but the minus sign. I am copying the data from a website, and I guess it is using a different character encoding. Are there functions in Excel for handling character encoding?

Comment: See my answer, it addresses the minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `SUBSTITUTE` to get rid of the currency character, e.g.

```
= SUBSTITUTE(D43,"£","")
```

And you could wrap the whole thing around a `VALUE` function, e.g.

```
= VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D43,"£",""))
```

If you have issues with "long dash" vs. "short dash", (`−` vs. `-`), you can do this:

```
= VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D43,"£",""),"−","-"))
```

Short dashes are required for Excel to recognize the string as a number.

Comment: thanks. I tried your first solution, and then realised it was the minus sign not the pound sign causing the problem.

Comment: Yes I realized that also after I posted the answer haha. Please mark my answer as correct if this works for you.

Comment: The value function doesnt seem to mind the pound sign , so just a single substitute should work =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D43,"−","-"))

Comment: Thanks @TomSharpe. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(LEFT(D43,2)="−£",-VALUE(MID(D43,3,LEN(D43)-2)),VALUE(D43))
```

This seems to do the job, but would be interested if there is a better/simpler solution.